# How to use a 'for' loop to iterate nested-list index items in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, nested

I have a list like this:

```
nList = [[0,0,0],[3,2,1]],\ [[]],\ [[100,1000,110]],\ [[0,0,0],[300,400,300],[300,400,720],[0,0,120],[100,0,1320],[30,500,1450]]
```

and need to store the outputs in such a manner so as every variable before '\' comes out like this, for example, before the 1st '\':

```
0 metres, 0 metres, 0 seconds
3 metres, 2 metres, 1 seconds
```

I have come up with this so far for individual indexes before each '\', for example for `nList[4]`:

```
outputList = []

for distance in nList[4]:
    outputLlist.append('{} metres, {} metres, {} seconds'.format(*distance))
```

But how do I create a `for` loop that iterates over all `nList` indexes and stores the output in format `'x' metres, 'y' metres, 't' seconds` in empty list `outputList`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,len(nList)):
    for distance in nList[i]:
        outputLlist.append('{} metres, {} metres, {} seconds'.format(*distance))
```

I think this will do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

So your data structure is a tuple of lists of lists.
You will need two loops.

```
outputList = []
for i in nList:
    for distance in i:
        outputList.append('{} metres, {} metres, {} seconds'.format(*distance))
```

But you can also use a list comprehension:

```
outputList = ['{} metres, {} metres, {} seconds'.format(*distance)) 
              for i in nList for distance in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each sub-list in the list, and check that each element has 3 or more entries before outputting it:

```
nList = [[0,0,0],[3,2,1]], [[]], [[100,1000,110]], [[0,0,0],[300,400,300],[300,400,720],[0,0,120],[100,0,1320],[30,500,1450]] 

outputList = []

for subList in nList:
    for distance in subList:
        if len(distance) >= 3:
            outputList.append('{} metres, {} metres, {} seconds'.format(*distance))
```